# How do I avoid having to delete content and make it again when changing a template in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I've noticed that when I change a document type's template in Umbraco (by using the Allowed Templates tool under the Templates tab) I get a "can't bind models" error unless I delete any pages with the document type and make them again.

Is there any way to avoid this? Am I changing the page's template in the wrong way?

Thanks

Louise

Comment: Which version of Umbraco are you using? This problem doesn't sounds familiar to me

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question - check the ~/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog file immediately after you get this error and see if there's an exception logged there - this sounds to me like a mis-configured ModelsBuilder issue, but won't know for sure without more information.

Comment: Are you doing anything else like deleting the old template or changing the old template? After you change the allowed template, are you actually changing the nodes to use the new template?

Comment: I didn't realise you have to update the node itself to use the new template :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise you have to update the node itself to use the new template :)